# removing an element in array within map in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mapping

On the click of the span, i want to remove that element from the array and run the map again so that the spans also gets removed. I don't know if the syntax is wrong or what. This is the link to sandbox where I wrote my code. https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-wu-4dd11?file=/src/App.js

```js
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const data = [{
      name: "Alex",
    },
    {
      name: "John",
    },
    {
      name: "Leo",
    },
    {
      name: "Murphy",
    },
    {
      name: "Alex",
    },
    {
      name: "John",
    },
    {
      name: "Leo",
    },
    {
      name: "Murphy",
    },
  ];

  return ( <
    div className = "App" > {
      data.map(function(val, id) {
        return ( <
          span key = {
            id
          }
          className = "select__item"
          onClick = {
            (e) => {
              data.splice(data.indexOf(val), id + 1);
              console.log(data);
            }
          } >
          {
            val.name
          } < br / > < br / >
          <
          /span>
        );
      })
    } <
    /div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You should use `useState` hook to store the data and update it. React cannot magically trigger a rerender when some variable changes.

Comment: You should use `useState` for this to work. The way you do it right now neither trigger a re-rendering, nor modifies the original array.

Comment: Can you show me the example. I am new to react and sometimes i get stuck with the syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `useState` hook in this case, because React won't re-render automatically. You have to tell react externally, one way is to change state and react will rerender components automatically as:

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([
        {
            name: "Alex",
        },
        {
            name: "John",
        },
        {
            name: "Leo",
        },
        {
            name: "Murphy",
        },
        {
            name: "Alex",
        },
        {
            name: "John",
        },
        {
            name: "Leo",
        },
        {
            name: "Murphy",
        },
    ]);

    const removeItem = (index) => {
        setData(data.filter((o, i) => index !== i));
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {data.map(function (val, id) {
                return (
                    <span
                        key={id}
                        className="select__item"
                        onClick={() => removeItem(id)}>
                        {val.name} <br />
                        <br />
                    </span>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind, prefer this syntax `const removeItem = (index) => () => setData(d.filter((_, i) => index !== i));` and `onClick={removeItem(id)}` to avoid  that a different callback is created each time it renders

Comment: @MichaelArbib What is the difference between your snippet and the code that I've suggested?

Comment: I am sending data to the component through prop. What should I do about it?

Comment: @GhayasUdDin Pass a function from parent to child i.e. `removeItem` and then call it as soon as user click on `span`

Comment: @Andy not really because it is `(id) => () => { ... }` and not just `(id) => { ... }`
@decpk i am just refering React docs, i should have put it at the beginning https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

```
function handleRemove(id) {
  // this  work for me 
  const newList = this.state.newList.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
 this.setState({newList});
}
```